# Breadcrumb not show on my page in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have two page A and B.

This is a page A, i want to click to a category item on page A and redirect to page B:

[image]

This is a page B, but breadcrumb is not show on my page B.

But it will show if i click to a category item on page B.

[image]

I want breadcrumb show on after loaded the first page.

Look like "`Trang chủ/{category_name}`"

[image]

Comment: IMHO the breadcrumb you see is for pages only..

Comment: Voting to close as off topic here: There's no custom code involved, and [stackoverflow is about writing code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'm suggesting to come over to the Liferay forums, where this would be on topic.